# Работа с кортежами в классах Python вывести по индексу

Tags: python, ооп

Помогите понять как при создании экземпляра класса, вывести данные из кортежа по индексу?

Вот код:

```
class Year():
    ### кортеж временами года
    seasons = ("Зима", "Весна", "Лето", "Осень")
    
    ### Кортеж с месяцами
    months = ("Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель",
             "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь",
             "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь")
    
    ### Кортеж с днями
    days = ("Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг", "Пятница", "Суббота", "Воскресенье")

    """ Инициализируем методы """
    def __init__(self, seasons, months, days):
        self.seasons = seasons
        self.months = months
        self.days = days

    def printYear(self):
        print("Время года: " + self.seasons + " Месяц: " + self.months + " День недели: " + self.days)

""" Попытка вывести по индексу """
Year1 = Year(seasons[0], months[0], days[0]) ### Ошибка NameError: name 'seasons' is not defined

print(printYear())
```

Comment: seasons, months, days у вас внутри класса лежат, они доступны через класс: Year.seasons, Year.months, Year.days. Но в `__init__` вы зачем-то перезаписываете их. Вообще так делать не нужно, лучше, например, в printYear передать индексы, а внутри уже получать нужные значения.

Comment: printYear, кстати, тоже внутри класса, его нужно вызывать как метод класса от объекта этого класса.

Comment: " нужно вызывать как метод класса от объекта этого класса." - М... можете кодом показать? Я немного не понял. Пожалуйста.

Comment: Через точку обращаться, как и ко всему, что внутри класса или объекта: `Year1.printYear()`

Answer (score 0):

Тут происходит следующее:
Вы инициализируете экземпляр класса Year с именем Year1, передавая для инициализации элементы кортежей seasons, months и days.

Таких кортежей не существует.

Кортежи с такими именами являются переменными класса Year.

Для получения значения переменной экземпляра класса можно сделать так:

```
Year1 = Year  # объявляем экземпляр класса
print(Year1.seasons, Year1.months, Year1.days)  # выводим значения переменных экземпляра класса
print(Year1.seasons[0], Year1.months[0], Year1.days[0])  # ну и для получения элемента кортежа по индексу используется стандартный подход
```

Comment: "Таких кортежей не существует." - кортежи в самом классе, посмотрите код который я привёл выше

Comment: @Василий, ознакомьтесь с ответом и описанием ошибки в интерпретаторе еще раз. Если кортежи есть в описании класса - это не значит, что кортежи существуют (изучите области видимости), тем более без объявления экземпляров класса.